Web Automation using Python Script and Selenium in Microsoft Edge: Error in saving data
I was trying to automate the data entry process in a website.

The server is too slow
The data entry process is hectic as there are tens of thousands of entries need to be made in the website
The elements are loaded dynamically
Only the intended section of the webpage is targeted.
Wait times are included to ensure element interaction

I tried to automate the process using python and selenium. I used web driver for Microsoft Edge. There is something wrong with the code that it fails to save the data every single time.
The following is the full code that I used.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd
import time

# Load Excel data
excel_file = "***FILE PATH***"

# Load Habitation Code (Column B) and data from Columns H to P
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, usecols="B,H:P", skiprows=0)
df.columns = ['Habitation Code'] + [f'Field_{i}' for i in range(1, 10)]

# Function to format decimal values
def format_decimal(value):
    if pd.isna(value):
        return ''
    try:
        # Check if the value contains a decimal point
        if '.' in str(value):
            # Convert to float for formatting
            return f"{float(value):.3f}"
        else:
            # Return the value as is if it's a whole number
            return str(value)
    except ValueError:
        return str(value)

# Apply formatting to relevant fields
for col in df.columns[1:]:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(format_decimal)

# Configure Edge options to disable notifications and dialogs
edge_options = Options()
edge_options.add_argument("--disable-notifications")
edge_options.add_argument("--disable-popup-blocking")

# Path to Edge WebDriver executable
edge_driver_path = "C:\\WebDriver\\Edge\\msedgedriver.exe"

# Set up the Edge Service and WebDriver
service = Service(executable_path=edge_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=edge_options)

# Open the URL
driver.get('***URL***')

# Maximize the browser window
driver.maximize_window()

# Initialize WebDriverWait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

# Wait for the page to load
time.sleep(20)

# Locate and interact with login elements
try:
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id=':r2:']"))).send_keys('***USER ID***')
    wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, 'eyePassword'))).send_keys('***PASSWORD***')
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Login']"))).click()
    print("Login successful.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during login: {e}")
    driver.quit()

# Wait for the "Expand More" SVG element and click it
try:
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[data-testid='ExpandMoreIcon']"))).click()
    # Wait for the "Schema" SVG element and click it
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[data-testid='SchemaIcon']"))).click()
    # Wait for the "Edit" SVG element and click it
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "svg[data-testid='EditIcon']"))).click()
    print("Navigated to Edit page.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error during navigation: {e}")
    driver.quit()

# Locate and click the fifth "show more" button
try:
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[aria-label='show more']")))[4].click()
    time.sleep(15)
    print("Clicked the fifth 'show more' button.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error finding 'show more' button: {e}")
    driver.quit()

# Function to input data into table rows
def fill_table_data():
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        habitation_code = row['Habitation Code']
        data_columns = row[1:].tolist()  # Get data from columns H to P
        updated = False  # Flag to track if any value was updated

        try:
            # Find the row element by habitation code
            row_xpath = f"//tr[td[2][contains(text(), '{habitation_code}')]]"
            row_element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, row_xpath)))
            print(f"Found row for Habitation Code {habitation_code}")

            # Locate all input fields in the last 9 <td> elements of the row
            for j in range(7, 16):  # From the 8th to the 16th <td> (0-indexed)
                try:
                    # Construct the XPath for the input field within the j-th <td> element
                    input_xpath = f"{row_xpath}/td[{j+1}]/div/div/input"
                    input_field = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, input_xpath)))

                    # Scroll to the input field
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", input_field)

                    # Format the new value
                    new_value = data_columns[j - 7]  # Get new value from data_columns

                    # Use JavaScript to directly set the value of the input field
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = arguments[1];", input_field, new_value)
                    # Trigger change event to ensure data is saved
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));", input_field)

                    # Read back the value from the input field to verify
                    entered_value = input_field.get_attribute('value')
                    formatted_entered_value = format_decimal(entered_value)
                    print(f"Attempted to populate input in column {j+1} with data: {new_value}")
                    print(f"Actual value in input field for column {j+1}: {formatted_entered_value}")

                    # Compare and handle discrepancies
                    if formatted_entered_value != new_value:
                        print(f"Discrepancy detected in column {j+1} for Habitation Code {habitation_code}. Expected: {new_value}, Found: {formatted_entered_value}")
                        # Clear the field if values do not match
                        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].value = '';", input_field)
                        time.sleep(1)
                        continue

                    print(f"Successfully populated input in column {j+1} with data: {new_value}")
                    updated = True  # Set flag to true if a value was updated

                    # Wait 7 seconds before entering the next field
                    time.sleep(7)

                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error locating or filling input field in column {j+1} for Habitation Code {habitation_code}: {e}")

            if updated:
                # Click the save button using the full XPath
                try:
                    # Ensure the save button is in view
                    save_button_xpath = "//button[contains(@class, 'MuiButton-containedSAVE') and @type='submit']"
                    save_button = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, save_button_xpath)))
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", save_button)

                    # Use JavaScript to click the button if standard click fails
                    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", save_button)

                    print("Clicked the save button.")

                    # Wait for 90 seconds to ensure data is saved
                    time.sleep(90)
                except Exception as e:
                    print(f"Error clicking save button: {e}")

                print(f"Saved data for Habitation Code {habitation_code}")

        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error processing row with Habitation Code {habitation_code}: {e}")

# Call the function to fill table data
fill_table_data()

# Keep the browser open until manually closed
print("Browser is open. Press Ctrl+C in the terminal to close it.")

# Keep the browser open indefinitely
try:
    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("Browser closed.")

# Close the browser
driver.quit()

The send keys method for populating input fields did not work as expected.
The manual save button click generates a "Saved successfully" pop-up message in the webpage and it disappears almost instantly. But I don't know how to tell the script to wait for that message and move on to the next entry.
There are more than one save buttons in the web page and I tried using the full XPath method and JavaScript to click the save button, but it does not seem to work. What is going wrong here?
he web page is opened almost instantly. Login was successful. The intended section is navigated through. Values can be seen populated. But data saving is not happening. Python Terminal shows everything populated successfully.
Please do offer a solution to this issue.
