Puppeteer: Unable to identify an element on the web page
I want to automate a bulk data entry process. I have data in my excel file that exactly matches the table structure on my web page. I need to login and navigate to the table after a few clicks. I was able to navigate through till identifying the table. But I'm stuck on an error loop that keeps saying "Row with Identifier #####[A number that is being searched, more like a look up value] not found". I tried my best but still could not figure out what is wrong. I'm using the latest version of puppeteer and Node.js.
Here's a nutshell of my objective.

Login to my portal
Navigate to the desired section
Take data from my excel file.
Use value from one column, identify it on the web page and fill values for that row from excel file.
There will be so many rows in excel so it will be run through a loop

I tested it with one row but something seems to be wrong with the code.
Here's the code
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const XLSX = require('xlsx');

(async () => {
  try {
    // Launch browser
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless: false,
      defaultViewport: null,
      args: ['--start-maximized']
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();

    // Navigate to the login page
    await page.goto('***URL***', { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

    // Type username and password
    await page.waitForSelector('#\\:r2\\:'); 
    await page.type('#\\:r2\\:', '***USERNAME***');
    await page.waitForSelector('#eyePassword');
    await page.type('#eyePassword', '***PASSWORD***');

    // Click the login button
    await page.waitForFunction(() => {
      return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'))
        .some(button => button.textContent.includes('Login'));
    }, { timeout: 60000 });
    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const buttons = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('button'));
      for (const button of buttons) {
        if (button.textContent.includes('Login')) {
          button.click();
          return;
        }
      }
    });

    // Wait for navigation
    await page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

    // Custom delay function
    const delay = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

    // Click the Account Tree Icon
    await delay(2000); // Increased wait before clicking
    await page.waitForSelector('svg[data-testid="AccountTreeIcon"]');
    await page.click('svg[data-testid="AccountTreeIcon"]');

    // Click the Schema Icon
    await delay(2000); // Increased wait before clicking
    await page.waitForSelector('svg[data-testid="SchemaIcon"]');
    await page.click('svg[data-testid="SchemaIcon"]');

    // Click the Edit Icon
    await delay(2000); // Increased wait before clicking
    await page.waitForSelector('svg[data-testid="EditIcon"]');
    await page.click('svg[data-testid="EditIcon"]');

    // Click the button inside the fifth div
    await page.waitForSelector('div.MuiCardActions-root.Scheme_cardActions__G6Wox', { visible: true });

    await page.evaluate(() => {
      const divs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('div.MuiCardActions-root.Scheme_cardActions__G6Wox'));

      console.log(`Number of divs found: ${divs.length}`); // Debugging log

      if (divs.length >= 5) {
        const fifthDiv = divs[4]; // The fifth div
        console.log('Fifth div:', fifthDiv); // Debugging log
        const button = fifthDiv.querySelector('button.MuiButtonBase-root.MuiIconButton-root.MuiIconButton-sizeMedium');

        if (button) {
          console.log('Button found. Clicking...'); // Debugging log
          button.click();
        } else {
          console.error('Button not found in the fifth div.');
        }
      } else {
        console.error('Less than 5 divs found.');
      }
    });

    // Wait for 40 seconds after clicking the last button
    await delay(40000);

    // Select the specific table using XPath via evaluate
    const tableHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() => {
      const xpath = '//*[@id="root"]/div[2]/main/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/form/div/div[1]/div/div/div/table';
      const result = document.evaluate(xpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
      return result.singleNodeValue;
    });

    if (!tableHandle) {
      throw new Error('Table not found.');
    }

    // Load Excel data
    const workbook = XLSX.readFile("D:\\Work\\867\\867_Demand_Test.xlsx");
    const sheet = workbook.Sheets[workbook.SheetNames[0]];
    const jsonData = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(sheet, { header: 1 }); // Get raw data including header row

    // Filter out empty rows
    const nonEmptyRows = jsonData.filter(row => row.length > 0);

    // Define column mappings from Excel to web page
    const headerRow = nonEmptyRows[0]; // Header row
    const dataRows = nonEmptyRows.slice(1); // Skip header row
    const headerMap = {
      identifier: 'Habitation Code', // Updated to exact header name
      dataColumns: ['H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P'] // Data columns H to P
    };

    console.log('Header Row:', headerRow); // Log header row for debugging
    console.log('Data Rows:', dataRows); // Log data rows for debugging

    // Iterate over the data rows
    for (const row of dataRows) {
      // Ensure the row is not empty
      if (row.length === 0) {
        console.warn('Empty row encountered. Skipping.');
        continue;
      }

      const identifier = row[headerRow.indexOf(headerMap.identifier)]; // Identifier column

      console.log(`Processing row with identifier: ${identifier}`); // Log identifier for debugging

      if (!identifier) {
        console.error(`Identifier is missing in the row: ${row}`);
        continue;
      }

      // Debug the presence of rows and identifiers in the selected table
      const tableRows = await page.evaluate((tableElement) => {
        return Array.from(tableElement.querySelectorAll('tr.MuiTableRow-root.MuiTableRow-hover'))
          .map(row => ({
            text: row.innerText.trim(),
            identifier: row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)') ? row.querySelector('td:nth-child(2)').innerText.trim() : null
          })); // Extract text and identifier for debugging
      }, tableHandle);

      console.log('Table Rows:', tableRows); // Log table rows for debugging

      // Find the row in the selected table with the matching identifier
      const rowSelector = await page.evaluate(async (identifier, tableElement) => {
        const rows = Array.from(tableElement.querySelectorAll('tr.MuiTableRow-root.MuiTableRow-hover'));
        for (const row of rows) {
          const cells = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'));
          const rowIdentifier = cells[1] ? cells[1].textContent.trim() : null;
          if (rowIdentifier === identifier) {
            row.scrollIntoView(); // Scroll to the row if needed
            return row; // Return the row element
          }
        }
        throw new Error(`Row with identifier '${identifier}' not found.`);
      }, identifier, tableHandle);

      if (!rowSelector) {
        console.error(`Row with identifier '${identifier}' not found.`);
        continue;
      }

      // Fill in the data
      await page.evaluate((selector, data) => {
        const row = document.querySelector(selector);
        if (!row) return;

        const cells = row.querySelectorAll('td');

        if (cells.length >= 9) {
          cells[7].querySelector('input').value = data[0] || '';
          cells[8].querySelector('input').value = data[1] || '';
          cells[9].querySelector('input').value = data[2] || '';
          cells[10].querySelector('input').value = data[3] || '';
          cells[11].querySelector('input').value = data[4] || '';
          cells[12].querySelector('input').value = data[5] || '';
          cells[13].querySelector('input').value = data[6] || '';
          cells[14].querySelector('input').value = data[7] || '';
          cells[15].querySelector('input').value = data[8] || '';
        }
      }, rowSelector, row);

      // Optionally, take a screenshot for debugging
      await page.screenshot({ path: 'screenshot.png' });

      await delay(7000); // Wait 7 seconds after each input
    }

    // Keep the browser open for manual interactions
    console.log('Waiting indefinitely. Press Ctrl+C to close the browser.');
    await new Promise(() => {}); // Keeps the browser open indefinitely

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
})();

OUTPUT:
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\867Script.js
Header Row: (16) […, 'Habitation Code', 'Habitation Name', 'Block', 'District', 'Panchayat', 'Forecast Method', 'Forecast-Base (Year 2024)', 'Forecast-Intermediate (Year 2039)', 'Forecast-Ultimate (Year 2054)', 'Demand-Base (in KL) (Year 2024)', 'Demand-Intermediate (in KL) (Year 2039)', 'Demand-Ultimate (in KL) (Year 2054)', 'Quantity Local Source', 'Quantity TWAD Source', 'Existing Scheme']
Data Rows: (1) [Array(16)]
Processing row with identifier: 949805
Table Rows: (868) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
Error: Error: Row with identifier '949805' not found.
    at evaluate (evaluate at D:\Work\Learning\JavaScript\867Script.js:146:38, <anonymous>:10:14)
    at #evaluate (d:\Work\Learning\JavaScript\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\ExecutionContext.js:386:56)
    at async ExecutionContext.evaluate (d:\Work\Learning\JavaScript\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\ExecutionContext.js:273:16)
    at async IsolatedWorld.evaluate (d:\Work\Learning\JavaScript\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\IsolatedWorld.js:99:16)
    at async CdpFrame.evaluate (d:\Work\Learning\JavaScript\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Frame.js:338:20)
    at async CdpPage.evaluate (d:\Work\Learning\JavaScript\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Page.js:826:20)
    at async D:\Work\Learning\JavaScript\867Script.js:146:27 {name: 'Error', stack: "Error: Row with identifier '949805' not found…rk\\Learning\\JavaScript\\867Script.js:146:27", message: "Row with identifier '949805' not found."}

Expanding the table rows, I got the following
arg1: (868) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, …]
185: {text: '186\t949805\tA.KRISHNAPURAM\tCHELLAMPATTI\tMADURAI…UPATTY\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​\n\t\n​', identifier: '949805'}


Suggestions..

Please share a [mcve]. Without '***URL***' there's no good way to assist. See also making spurious calls to waitForNavigation. Thanks.

I understand. I don't think sans the login credentials, the below URL will be of much assistance too.
http://twadpms.in/twadpms/
However I have trouble after this part
// Select the specific table using XPath via evaluate
const tableHandle = await page.evaluateHandle(() ....


For the same objective, I tried using selenium and python, yet it was an unsuccessful one too.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78804348/web-automation-using-python-script-and-selenium-in-microsoft-edge-error-in-savi

At least with the URL, if someone can sign up and reach the same page, then that'd be reproducible (instructions on how to sign up or whether it'd be possible are useful). Thanks.
